# How to set the JFrame's icon using a raw path to local storage

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, calculator

I need some help setting the JFrame's title bar icon as an image found in my computer.

I realize that the calculator is not complete. I still need to add the operations, however I just want to do this first.

If you could please focus on the actual question, that'd be astounding. Please don't suggest anything like setting a specific CLASSPATH. I want to grab the picture from my computer *without* using relative locations and the sort. I tried using relative locations before, however failed miserably.

This program is being done on *BlueJ*, simply due to personal preference.

The code for the image attempt is under the Calculator method...

The file path is "*C:/Users/Charlie/Downloads/smiley.png*"

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Calculator{
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Calculator");
    private String word = "";
    JTextField tf = new JTextField("0");
    public static void main(){
        Calculator Run = new Calculator();
    }
    public Calculator(){
        //URL url = new URL("file:/C:/Users/Charlie/Downloads/smiley.png");
        try{
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new
                com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel());
        }catch(Exception e){}
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("file:/C:/Users/Charlie/Downloads/smiley.png");
        f.setIconImage(img.getImage());
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);

        JButton one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, back, ce;
        one = new JButton("1");
        two = new JButton("2");
        three = new JButton("3");
        four = new JButton("4");
        five = new JButton("5");
        six = new JButton("6");
        seven = new JButton("7");
        eight = new JButton("8");
        nine = new JButton("9");
        zero = new JButton("0");
        back = new JButton("<-");
        ce = new JButton("CE");
        one.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        two.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        three.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        four.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        five.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        six.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        seven.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        eight.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        nine.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        zero.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        back.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        ce.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        one.setActionCommand("1");
        two.setActionCommand("2");
        three.setActionCommand("3");
        four.setActionCommand("4");
        five.setActionCommand("5");
        six.setActionCommand("6");
        seven.setActionCommand("7");
        eight.setActionCommand("8");
        nine.setActionCommand("9");
        zero.setActionCommand("0");
        back.setActionCommand("back");
        ce.setActionCommand("ce");
        one.addActionListener(al);
        two.addActionListener(al);
        three.addActionListener(al);
        four.addActionListener(al);
        five.addActionListener(al);
        six.addActionListener(al);
        seven.addActionListener(al);
        eight.addActionListener(al);
        nine.addActionListener(al);
        zero.addActionListener(al);
        back.addActionListener(al);
        ce.addActionListener(al);
        one.addKeyListener(kl);
        two.addKeyListener(kl);
        three.addKeyListener(kl);
        four.addKeyListener(kl);
        five.addKeyListener(kl);
        six.addKeyListener(kl);
        seven.addKeyListener(kl);
        eight.addKeyListener(kl);
        nine.addKeyListener(kl);
        zero.addKeyListener(kl);
        back.addKeyListener(kl);
        ce.addKeyListener(kl);
        f.addKeyListener(kl);

        tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 25));
        tf.setEditable(false);
        tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

        TitledBorder t0, t1, t2;
        t0 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Input ");
            t1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Operations ");
        t2 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" Output ");

        JPanel p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;
        p0 = new JPanel();
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p2 = new JPanel();
        p3 = new JPanel();
        p4 = new JPanel();
        p5 = new JPanel();
        p6 = new JPanel();
        p0.add(tf);
        p0.setBorder(t2);
        p1.add(one); p1.add(two); p1.add(three);
        p2.add(four); p2.add(five); p2.add(six);
        p3.add(seven); p3.add(eight); p3.add(nine);
        p4.add(ce);p4.add(zero); p4.add(back);
        p5.add(p1); p5.add(p2); p5.add(p3); p5.add(p4);
        p5.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p5, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p5.setBorder(t0);
        p6.add(p0); p6.add(p5);
        p6.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p6, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p6.addKeyListener(kl);

        f.add(p6);
        f.pack();
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        f.setLocation(dim.width/2 - f.getSize().width/2, dim.height/2 - f.getSize().height/2);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    KeyListener kl = new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(word.length() == 1 && word.equals("0")){
                word = "";
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_1)
                word += "1";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_2)
                word += "2";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_3)
                word += "3";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_4)
                word += "4";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_5)
                word += "5";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_6)
                word += "6";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_7)
                word += "7";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_8)
                word += "8";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_9)
                word += "9";
            else if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_0)
                word += "0";
            else if(word.length() > 1 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE){
                word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
            }
            else if((word.length() == 1 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || 
                     e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL ||
                    (word.length() == 0 && e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE))
                word = "0";
            else
                word = word;

            tf.setText(word);
        }
    };
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String action = e.getActionCommand();
            if(word.length() == 1 && word.equals("0")){
                word = "";
            }
            if(action.equals("1"))
                word += "1";
            else if(action.equals("2"))
                word += "2";
            else if(action.equals("3"))
                word += "3";
            else if(action.equals("4"))
                word += "4";
            else if(action.equals("5"))
                word += "5";
            else if(action.equals("6"))
                word += "6";
            else if(action.equals("7"))
                word += "7";
            else if(action.equals("8"))
                word += "8";
            else if(action.equals("9"))
                word += "9";
            else if(action.equals("0"))
                word += "0";
            else if(word.length() > 1 && action.equals("back")){
                word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
            }
            else if((word.length() == 1 && action.equals("back")) || action.equals("ce") ||
                     (word.length() == 0 && action.equals("back")))
                word = "0";
            tf.setText(word);
        }
    };
}
```

---

---

### Edit (0)

Well, I found an alternate solution to getting the image. I am still unsure about how to grab the image without a reference. I ended up making a separate class that grabs images, loads them and pulls them in for use. Here's the code for the image class:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageMake{
    private String path;
    private int[] pixels;
    public BufferedImage img;
    // You can make img static depending on how you use it.

    public ImageMake(String path){
        this.path = path;
        load();
    }
    public void load(){
        try{
            img = ImageIO.read(ImageMake.class.getResource(path));
            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();
            pixels = new int[w * h];
            img.getRGB(w, h, 0, 0, pixels, 0, w);
        }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Before I move on, I want to say that the `ImageMake.class` portion can be interchanged for `getClass()`, so the declaration would end up being:

`img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));`

So now, in another class, you would do something along the lines of this:

```
// Your code...
ImageMake image = new ImageMake("/res/textures/smiley.png");
genericJFrame.setIconImage(image.img); // This is just a random JFrame
// More of your code...
```

So now I will talk about some *important* things that people who have never dealt with images in java before (like myself) should know.

Remember in the ImageMake class that I posted above, there was code that went like:

```
img = ImageIO.read(ImageMake.class.getResource(path));
```

Well the ImageMake.class part references the folder where your class is on whatever storage device you're using.

In my case, the ImageMake class was in the directory: C:\Users\Charlie\Documents\Overall

In this same folder, I made another folder called "res" and then another folder inside that one called "textures" and then added a .png image called "smiley.png"

When you pass in the string 'path' for the image, it is starting the search within the folder which your class is located in. In my case I had to pass in "/res/textures/smiley.png" Make sure you're using the forward slash "/", otherwise you may get a compile-time error 'illegal escape character', or some run-time error.

So the overall, out-of-code directory to reach my image ended up being this: C:\Users\Charlie\Documents\Overall\res\textures\smiley.png

Here is the semi-finished code for the main class:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory.*;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calculator{
    private static JFrame f;
    private Font font;
    private boolean x = false, y = false;
    private double num, num1, num2, num3, ans;
    private int c = 0;
    private String word = "", save = "", keep = "";
    private JTextField tf = new JTextField("0");
    private static JPanel p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8, p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14;
    //private static ImageMake img = new ImageMake("/res/textures/smiley.png");
    public Calculator(){
        f = new JFrame("Calculator");
        try{
            javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new
                com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel());
        }catch(Exception e){}
        ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            titles.add("" + i);
        }
        titles.add("C");
        titles.add(".");
        titles.add("/");
        titles.add("*");
        titles.add("+");
        titles.add("-");
        titles.add("<");
        titles.add("=");

        for(int i = 0; i < titles.size(); i++){
            buttons.add(new JButton(titles.get(i)));
            buttons.get(i).addKeyListener(kl);
            buttons.get(i).addActionListener(al);
            buttons.get(i).setFocusable(false);
            if(i > 11 && i < 16)
            buttons.get(i).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        else if(i > 15)
            buttons.get(i).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 40));
        else
            buttons.get(i).setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 40));
        }

        font = new Font(Font.MONOSPACED, Font.PLAIN, 24);
        tf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(290, 60));
        tf.setEditable(false);
        tf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        tf.setFont(font);

        TitledBorder t0, t1, t2, t3;
        t0 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" INPUT ");
        t1 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(" OPERATIONS ");

        p0 = new JPanel();
        p1 = new JPanel();
        p2 = new JPanel();
        p3 = new JPanel();
        p4 = new JPanel();
        p5 = new JPanel();
        p6 = new JPanel();
        p7 = new JPanel();
        p8 = new JPanel();
        p9 = new JPanel();
        p10 = new JPanel();
        p11 = new JPanel();
        p12 = new JPanel();
        p13 = new JPanel();
        p14 = new JPanel();

        p0.add(tf);
        p14.add(p0);
        p1.add(buttons.get(1)); p1.add(buttons.get(2)); p1.add(buttons.get(3));
        p2.add(buttons.get(4)); p2.add(buttons.get(5)); p2.add(buttons.get(6));
        p3.add(buttons.get(7)); p3.add(buttons.get(8)); p3.add(buttons.get(9));
        p4.add(buttons.get(10)); p4.add(buttons.get(0)); p4.add(buttons.get(11));
        p5.add(p1); p5.add(p2); p5.add(p3); p5.add(p4);
        p5.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p5, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p5.setBorder(t0);
        p6.add(buttons.get(16));
        p7.add(buttons.get(12)); p7.add(buttons.get(13));
        p8.add(buttons.get(14)); p8.add(buttons.get(15));
        p9.add(buttons.get(17));
        p10.add(p6); p10.add(p7); p10.add(p8); p10.add(p9);
        p10.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p10, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        p10.setBorder(t1);
        p11.add(p5); p11.add(p10);
        p12.add(p14); p12.add(p11);
        p12.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p12, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        f.addKeyListener(kl);
        f.add(p12);
    }
    public static void main(){
        new Calculator();
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //f.setIconImage(img.img);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setFocusable(true);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void operationType(String operation){
        if(operation.equals("=")){
            num2 = num3;
            operation = keep;
        }
        switch(operation){
            case "/": num = (num1 / num2); word = "" + num; break;
            case "*": num = (num1 * num2); word = "" + num; break;
            case "+": num = (num1 + num2); word = "" + num; break;
            case "-": num = (num1 - num2); word = "" + num; break;
        }
        num1 = num;
    }
    KeyListener kl = new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            int press = e.getKeyCode();
            if(!word.equals("") && !word.equals("/") && !word.equals("*") && !word.equals("+") && !word.equals("-") && !word.equals(".")) ans = Double.parseDouble(word);
            if((word.equals("0") && press != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && press != KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS) || 
                word.equals("/") ||
                word.equals("*") ||
                word.equals("+") ||
                word.equals("-") || x){
                word = "";
                x = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyChar() == '+'){
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(word); word = save = keep = "+";
            }
            switch(press){
                case KeyEvent.VK_1: word += "1"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_2: word += "2"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_3: word += "3"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_4: word += "4"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_5: word += "5"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_6: word += "6"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_7: word += "7"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_8: word += "8"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_9: word += "9"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_0: word += "0"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_PERIOD: word += "."; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_SLASH: num1 = ans; word = save = keep = "/"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_X: num1 = ans; word = save = keep = "*"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_MINUS: num1 = ans; word = save = keep = "-"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_ENTER:
                if(save.equals("=")){
                    num2 = ans; x = true; operationType(save);}
                else{
                    num2 = ans; num3 = num2; save = "="; x = true; operationType(save);} break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE:
                if(word.length() > 1)
                    word = word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
                else if(word.length() == 1 || word.length() == 0)
                    word = "0"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE: word = "0"; break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL: word = "0";
            }
            tf.setText(word);
        }
    };
    ActionListener al = new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String action = e.getActionCommand();
            if(!word.equals("") && !word.equals("/") && !word.equals("*") && !word.equals("+") && !word.equals("-") && !word.equals(".")) ans = Double.parseDouble(word);
            if((word.equals("0") && !action.equals("=")) ||
                word.equals("/") || 
                word.equals("*") || 
                word.equals("+") || 
                word.equals("-") || x){
                word = "" ;
                x = false;
            }
            switch(action){
                case "1": word += "1"; break;
                case "2": word += "2"; break;
                case "3": word += "3"; break;
                case "4": word += "4"; break;
                case "5": word += "5"; break;
                case "6": word += "6"; break;
                case "7": word += "7"; break;
                case "8": word += "8"; break;
                case "9": word += "9"; break;
                case "0": word += "0"; break;
                case ".": word += "."; break;
                case "/": num1 = ans; word = save = keep = "/"; break;
                case "*": num1 = ans; word = save = keep = "*"; break;
                case "+": num1 = ans; word = save = keep = "+"; break;
                case "-": num1 = ans; word = save = keep = "-"; break;
                case "=":
                if(save.equals("=")){
                    num2 = ans; x = true; operationType(save);}
                else{
                    num2 = ans; num3 = num2; save = "="; x = true; operationType(save);} break;
                case "<":
                if(word.length() > 1)
                    word = word.substring(0, word.length() - 1);
                else if(word.length() == 1 || word.length() == 0)
                    word = "0"; break;
                case "C": word = "0"; break;
            }
            tf.setText(word);
        }
    };
}
```

It still has a couple of underlying errors that need to be fixed though.

Comment: I tremendously appreciate the edits fellow stackoverflow members. This community seems to work very hard in making sure only the important aspects of a question are involved. However, I do not appreciate the down-vote(s) on the question. I feel that it followed the guidelines in being clear about what the question was, and there shouldn't have been anything confusing about it. I researched endlessly online for an answer however people only offered alternate methods that went around what the OP wanted. Down-voting this for no good reason only makes it harder for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static ImageIcon createIcon(String spec) {
    URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource(spec);
    if (url != null) {
        return new ImageIcon(url); 
    }
    try {
        return new ImageIcon(new URL(spec));
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        return new ImageIcon(spec);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I had tried something like that once earlier. At the time I hadn't used a full `class` to do such a thing. I had simply instantiated an `ImageIcon` object in the calculator class and did something similar as to what you did. Unfortunately when you perform the `frame.setIconImage(icon)` it gives an error saying it was expecting an `Image` and not an `ImageIcon`. Even if I try to cast it as an `Image`, it gives an error saying I am not allowed to make that cast (due to being `abstract`). Do you perhaps know of a way to get it work by making an after having made the `ImageIcon`?